# React Native: get value for Text element from method

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to call a method to fill a View element with a Text element in React Native by returning it in a method:

> < View>{this._getCategories(item)}< /View>

The _getCategories method returns a Text element after it uses the item parameter to retrieve the correct data. A simplified version would look like this:

```
_getCategories = item => {
names = 'some string';
      console.log(names); //this logs the correct string
      return <Text style={styles.categories}>{names}</Text>;  
};
```

The Text element does not appear in the application, shows undefined if I use {String(names)} in the View element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried both `{String(names)}` and `{names}` , it works fine. May be there is a problem in your retrieving method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the problem appeared to be somewhere else (regarding a promise). I'll just mark this as the accepted answer.